# C# How to get data into an array within an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to build a CD collection program in C# that can

1. Create a new album (ie, add a new entry in your album database)
2. Change or delete an existing album in your album database
3. Enter the details of a piece of music (title, artist, genre, and the length of the music) into an album
4. Change or delete the details of an existing music in an album
5. List the details of all music in a given album
6. List all music by a given artist
7. List all music in your database. Your program must allow the user to choose the order of listing: by album, by artist, by genre, or by title.

I'm stuck on the 3rd bit, adding details to each album, so far i have this, i figure when i get this right, the rest of the details will be easy to add

```
public bool AddSong(string songName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MUSIC; i++)
        {
            string c = albumName;                   // This compares the album name given by user
            string e = myMusic[i].getAlName;        // to the album name in the myMusic array
            int d = c.CompareTo(e);                 //
            if (d == 0)
            {
                int index = -1;
                for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SONG; j++)
                {
                    if (Songs[i] == null)
                    {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    Songs[index] = songName;
                    ++totalSongs;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }


        return false;

    }
```

any help to give me direction would be much appreciated.

EDIT: This is homework, I'm an external student and my lecturer as nice as he is, doesn't speak english very well, I don't expect freebies. Just direction on approach and maybe an odd hint ;)

EDIT2: My code is very large so i dont think it is appropriated to post such large amounts of code, i can though provide a link to the classes

[musicDB.cs](http://codepad.org/kbJ9KQTA)

[music.cs](http://codepad.org/jIeh9dTm)

[Form1.cs](http://codepad.org/W960Lbyf)

Comment: Is this for education purposes? Why don't you use a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` or something similar?

Comment: can you post more of the code so I can see more of what's going on?

Comment: Its a bit hard to answer not knowing how much you have learned already, but I would assume you need to use a custom class that you would design to hold your SongName string, along with the other information you want to include...

Comment: What is the structure of `Songs`?

Comment: By the way, most programs, like media players, only have a long 1-dimensional list of songs, not lists of artists containing lists of albums containing lists of songs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SONG; j++)
>             {
>                 if (Songs[i] == null)
>                 {
>                     index = i;
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
> ```

You're looping through j but you're not using j in your for loop. So you're really doing the same thing MAX_SONG times.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (index != -1)
{
     Songs[index] = songName;
     ++totalSongs;
     return true;
}
```

This is the section you need to focus on now.

Ask yourself:

1. How to create a new `Song` class (initialize)?
2. How to set properties on the `Song` class?
3. Finally, how to apply the `Song` to the correct position in the array?

Comment: So i need to make a songs class, just as i did for albums?

Comment: Since your point 3 has many properties of the song to save, I would suggest that you need some sort of structure to keep those properties.  Good luck!